# How to update value from apex class with process builder

Tags: apex, soql, community, process-builder

Hi friends i am new to sfdc.I want to update a value in account object from custom object through process builder with apex class.I tried to write an apex class and i create a process whenever field value is changed this apex class will fire. for reference:

```
public class TestFieldUpdate {

    //Metod to delete contacts 
    @InvocableMethod
    public static void deleteContacts(List<Pi_Device__c> Deviceids)
    {
        List<String> s= new List<String> ();
        for(Pi_Device__c p:deviceids) {         
            s.Add(p.Customer_ID__c);
        }
        List<Account> contactListToDelete = [select id from account 
                                                       where Customer_ID__c IN : s];
        for(Account a:contactListToDelete) {
            for(Pi_Device__c pi: deviceids){
                if(pi.Customer_ID__c==a.Customer_ID__c)
                {
                    a.No_of_Devices_activated_in_Portal__c=pi.No_of_Devices_activated_in_Portal__c;
                }
            }
            Upsert a;
        }


    }    
}
```

But it throws an error Please help me in advance

Comment: Please add the error text...

Comment: An error occurred at element myRule_1_A1 (FlowActionCall).
An Apex error occurred: System.SObjectException: SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field: Customer_ID__c  @cropredy

Comment: Pavan -- you're killing yourself with variable names here - (1) are you passing in a list of SObjects from the Process or a list of IDs? (2) `s` should be named something like `customerIdSearchSet` (don't use a list as you want only unique customerIds) (3) `contactListToDelete` - yet you are upserting accounts, not contacts. (4) your upsert is inside a for loop

Comment: based on the error, i'd say that you are passing in an ID list  and then the invocable method should query the `PI_Device__c` to get all the fields.

Comment: i had already got it thanks for comment @cropredy But can you suggest i had wrote a process to work this like whenever field value is changed like boolean equal true.But my requirement is whenever record is inserted or updated it will work.But now it works only before insert can you suggest me validation criteria Thanks for help.

Comment: [declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries) seems like a much more natural fit... Are you trying to sum these fields? Because right now you are just arbitrarily selecting a child value, which doesn't make a ton of sense.

Comment: Pavan - 1) Please EDIT the original question with a) current code, b) screen shot of flow/process that invokes the method, and c) specific current problem. It is too hard to diagnose via successive reveals in comments

Comment: @cropredy You can type `[edit]` to create a link that allows OP to [edit] the question. Agreed that this question is near impossible to answer.

Comment: @AdrianLarson - thanks, didn't know that.  My brain needs to make room for yet another markup trick. I see there is also `[ask]` which would be relevant here too.